# Force Facebook & ActionScript to prompt user before publishing to his/her wall?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook, actionscript, facebook-graph-api

Hey there! So I got Facebook to work with Flash as I wanted it to using the Facebook-Actionscript-Api. Works great and I got get Graph api working so that I'm able to post stuff to ppl's walls using the Facebook.api("/me/feed") function.

It post stuff without asking the user permission, as it's already got that permission, and it's great for many occasions. But not all.

How can I enforce the 'publish to wall'-dialog?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to "remove" that permission each time before you try to publish to the user's wall. The user has to remove the permissions or the app themselves. You'll probably have to create your own dialog that informs the user that thew app is to publish to the feed and have accept/decline buttons within it.

You could do this right in flash or make a call to javascript via fbjs-bridge and launching a dialog:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ (look under Dialogs)

Comment: Ok, thanks! Reason I ask is I was thinking that if you ask the user permission then you can do an unlimited amount of posts to the users wall (as he approves all) but doing it automatically could end up just not working every time when a limit's gotten reached.